# Ubuntu 20.04 randomly freezing

Tags: 20.04, dell, freeze, lts

I am experiencing from long time random freezes on my latitude 7520.

Some days I have 2 to 3 freezes (the majority of times in the morning, one after another), then I can work all day long without problems.

In other days no freezes at all.

I have saved the output of journalctl of the entire day on a file, but I can't understand it's content.

Today I had 4 freezes between 12-13.30.

Can you help me understand what's happening?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OGNaoGqgmQxfngJ8vfP3yJpusyFa26nf/view?usp=share_link

Comment: How much RAM and swap do you have? `free` will tell you. Freezing is often caused by running our if RAM. Read `man free mkswap fallocate swapon fstab`.

Comment: Mem: 31839, Swap 975

At the moment I have 17gig of ram available, 975 of swap available

Comment: Your Google Drive link throws up an "Access Denied" message.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the file where you've saved the output of your journalctl, as the Google Drive link you've provided gives me an "Access Denied" message, but from your description of the problem, and going by personal experience, it sounds like you might be running out of available RAM.  When using my laptop (a Lenovo IdeaPad 3 with 12 GiB of RAM; currently running 22.04, but experienced exactly the same problem back when it was running 20.04), I've sometimes encountered Ubuntu suddenly freezing up at seemingly-random times, and remaining completely unresponsive, with inputs having absolutely no effect and the screen remaining frozen in time, for anywhere from 15-30 seconds to upwards of half an hour, before everything suddenly unfreezes; upon checking System Monitor in the aftermath of these freezes, I see that the memory-usage trace had been at essentially 100% during the freeze, before dropping by 15 to 30 percentage points at the moment the system started to respond again.

Going forwards, I'd suggest keeping an eye on your RAM usage and not running *too* many memory-intensive/memory-leaky programs at any one time.